# I can't install my TL-WN422G in ubuntu 12.10

Tags: wireless, 12.10, internet, connection

I have installed ubuntu 12.10 in my PC and removed windows 7, but i have a problem with my Tp link WN422G, it does not work, i try differents methodes to install it and it give no results. I need your help please, I am a Bigenner of Linux.

Comment: Please see this blogpost http://dinthsblog.blogspot.in/2010/04/i-was-fighting-to-run-tp-link-wn422g-v2.html

Answer (score 0):

Found This ( in french , i guess you understand it ! ) http://forum.ubuntu-fr.org/viewtopic.php?id=421628

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.